# BroadcastReceiver и стрессовые ситуации

Tags: android, многопоточность, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver

Допустим, есть 100 потоков для http-запросов и один `broadcastreceiver` для обработки всех `responses`. Сделаем 100 запросов и в течении ~2-3 секунд на `broadcastreceiver` будут приходить `response-callbacks`,каждый из которых обрабатывается за ~50 *мс*.

Вопросы:

  Что будет происходить с `broadcastreceiver` в этой ситуации, - если он, не успев обработать предыдущее сообщение, получит новое? Новые будут в очереди? Или пропускаться?
  Не лучше ли будет дать `receiver` обрабатывать сообщения в отдельном потоке, чтоб `UIMainThread` оставался плавным при анимации и пролистывании?

Comment: Лучше будет не использовать `broadcast` для таких задач. Если Вам нужно наладить "общение" активности и службы - для этого существует привязка: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services?hl=ru

Comment: @woesss , a если MVP? И нужна независимость активности и службы(последняя как составляющая model).